# custom widgets using ipywidgets in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidgets for creating a forms in jupyter notebooks which takes input from users and stores in database. While creating this forms I don't have all required widgets in ipywidgets so thought of creating a custom widgets and I am going through tutorial when I am trying this block of code but encountering an error. Don't know what's going wrong. Thanks in advance.

I am following this link :
https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Custom.html

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode, validate
```

```
class HelloWidget(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('HelloView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('hello').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
```

```
%%javascript

require.undef('hello');

define('hello', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {

    var HelloView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        // Render the view.
        render: function() {
            this.el.textContent = 'Hello World!';
        },
    });

    return {
        HelloView: HelloView
    };
});
```

Those three are three different cells When I run the third cell the error encountered is

`Javascript Error: require is not defined`